# A is a matrix, using Euclidean norm, why $\inf\{C\geq 0:||Ah||\leq C||h||$ for all $h\in\mathbb{R^n}\}=\sup\{||Ah||:h\in\mathbb{R^n}, ||h||=1\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Duistermaat's Multidimensional Real Analysis, on Page 40, it says:

The Euclidean norm (defined as $(\sum a_{ij}^2)^{1/2}$) of a linear operator $A$ is easy to to compute, but has the disadvantage of not giving the best possible estimate in inequality $||Ah||\leq ||A||_{eucl}||h||$, which would be

$\inf\{C\geq 0:||Ah||\leq C||h|| $ for all $ h\in\mathbb{R^n}\}$. (1)

It is easy to verify that this number is equal to the operator norm $||A||$ of $A$, give by

$\sup\{||Ah||:h\in\mathbb{R^n}, ||h||=1\}$. (2)

I don't understand why (1) is equal to (2)?

Comment: it should be $||Ah||\leq C||h||$

Comment: @MattAPelto thanks, edited.

Comment: Can you see it now then? Notice that since $A$ is linear, $\|Ah\|/\|h\|=\|A(h/\|h\|)\|$ ($h \neq 0$)

Comment: @MattAPelto So $\|A(h/\|h\|)\| \leq C$ for every C, so $\|A(h/\|h\|)\|\leq \inf\{C\}$ for every. $h$ , then $\sup \|A(h/\|h\|)\|\leq\inf\{C\}$, but I still don't understand why they're equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$G=\inf \left\{C\geq 0:\frac{\|Ah\|}{\|h\|}\leq C \text{ for all }  h \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} \right\}$$
and $$L=\sup \left\{\frac{\|Ah\|}{\|h\|}: h \neq 0 \right\}.$$

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.

We may find $h \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$  such that
$$ L < \frac{\|Ah\|}{\|h\|}+\varepsilon.$$
Having found $h$, we may then find $C \geq 0$ so that
$$ \frac{\|Ah\|}{\|h\|}- \varepsilon \leq C - \varepsilon<G.$$
Since $\|Ah\|/\|h\| \leq L$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$, we have $G \leq L$.

We combine to see that we have
$$L-2\varepsilon<\frac{\|Ah\|}{\|h\|}- \varepsilon < G \leq L.$$

Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we are left to conclude that $G=L$.

**Note:**

- If we have $\|Ah\| \leq G\|h\|$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$, then we have $\|Ah\| \leq G\|h\|$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ since $\|A0\| =0 = G\|0\|$.
- For $h \neq 0$ we have $h/\|h\|=1$.

Comment: Thanks, just why $G\leq \frac{\|Ah\|}{\|h\|}$?

Comment: my bad, what I first wrote was lazily and so poorly thought-out.